# Can't Get Cell to Focus on ContentEditable Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table that some columns are contenteditable and some are not. My HTML Includes the File: https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table/blob/master/mindmup-editabletable.js

If I Call Out:

```
$('#detail').editableTableWidget();
```

It works great, I can move from cell to cell from the arrow keys and the cells highlight on select,

But the only problem is that every column is contenteditable and I don't want that. If I call

```
$('#detail').editableTableWidget().find('[contenteditable]');
```

The Movement of the arrow keys work but not the highlight, It doesn't seem to work. How can i call this only on my contenteditable columns?

http://jsfiddle.net/2u3mhom8/ is a JSFiddle I Created to show my issue,

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution. I found something on their issues page on github that might work for you:

https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table/issues/6

I haven't tried that solution yet, but it looks elegant, and they point you directly to the lines of code that you need to change to get it to work.

Basically, you just use these:

`element.find("td:not([data-editable='no'])").on('click keypress dblclick', showEditor)`

and

`element.find("td:not([data-editable='no'])").prop('tabindex', 1);`

to replace the corresponding lines in "mindmup-editabletable.js", which are at line 92 and 113 (as of the time the post was written...not sure if they're still in the same spot).

I also found a slight workaround that I'm currently using in my own project because it's super simple and requires no code to implement (though you might have to do a bit more work with CSS to get the cells to look right). Instead of using  for your cells, use  that will make the cell uneditable.

Comment: OH, forgot to add that you need to add the data-editable='no' attribute to the <td> elements you don't want to give the user the ability to change.